# How do I include title and class attribute in link_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying this:

```
<%= link_to 'Test', '#', {title: "this is my images tooltop message", class: "tooltip"} %>
```

Which returns the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip">Test</a>
```

When I remove the `class` attribute, I then get:

```
<a href="#" title="this is my images tooltop message">Test</a>
```

How can I set both the `title` and `class` in the anchor tag so I get the following?

```
<a href="#" title="this is my images tooltop message" class="tooltip">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm useless! What I'm doing is in fact correct.

The tooltip jQuery plugin I'm using removes the title attribute - http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/.

Comment: I doubt it. Because When I had <%= link_to 'Show', '#', { :title => "this is my images tooltop message", :class => "tooltip"} %>
(The older hash syntax), both title and class appeared

Comment: This is because the javascript in the plugin I'm using removes the title field when a class of 'tooltip' has been added! Didn't realize!

Answer (score 3):

You can do also:

```
<%= link_to 'Test', '#', :class => "tooltip", :title => 'this is my images tooltop message' %>
```

it's just which hash notation you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to 'Show', '#', { :title => "this is my images tooltop message", :class => "tooltip"} %>
```

The older hash notation renders out the perfect HTML. I don't know why the new hash syntax results in this weird behavior though.

Comment: This is because the javascript in the plugin I'm using removes the title field when a class of 'tooltip' has been added! Didn't realize!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Test', '#', title: "this is my images tooltop message", class: "tooltip" %>
```

Comment: Don't supply code only, take the time to explain what it does for the user.

Comment: You're right, it was obvious to me but I wasn't the one that made the question.